# Why does the following "Battery" experiment work?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

I did the following experiment:

## **Experimental setup:**

**Two electrodes (one made out of Iron,the other made out of Copper)**
**are put into a (bluish) Copper(ii) sulfate lotion.**

[image]

**Then, one connect a voltmeter to them to measure the potential.**

[image]

**Finally, one disconnect the voltmeter and connect an Amperemeter to measure the electrical current.**

[image]

## **Observations:**

-Copper accumulates around the iron electrode,forming a thick copper coloured slick around it.

-there is a potential of about 0.5 V between the electrodes, which stays for several minutes.

-when one connect the amperemeter, one can measure a current which stays at least for a few seconds. (didn't measure further)

-there is no (visible) activity around the copper electrode.

-the solution doesn't change its colour notably.

-especially, one could not observe any evolution of gas. (although this does not mean that there is absolutely no gas evolution)

## **How is the measured tension and current caused?**

Comment: What's unclear about it? This is a simple galvanic cell.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin : There is just one chamber! AFAIK galvanic cells have two chambers.

Comment: All right, this is a _bad_  galvanic cell. So what? The reactions are the same.

Comment: Could you give a detailed description of the reactions going on?

Comment: Could _you_  do the same for a normal galvanic cell with two chambers?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin : Yes. I could do that for a normal galvanic cell. But this bad one is hard to understand.

Comment: Now imagine another situation: no wires, just an iron rod in the CuSO4 solution. Surely you must have heard about the substitution reaction which will take place here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93929/discussion-between-kgm-and-ivan-neretin).